# Is it possible to disable the "shutdown" option in Jupyter Notebook for a custom kernel?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, zeromq, jupyter-kernel

A part of my current thesis is about analyzing Jupyter Notebook. My professor asked me if it's possible to remove the possibility to shutdown a Kernel (forcefully) from a notebook (front-end).
The reason behind it is that we want to create an IoT Remote Lab which is getting controlled via Jupyter Notebook, using a custom (self-written) kernel.

At the moment the kernel is just working fine but I've implemented it as a wrapper kernel around IPython so I do not have a lot of freedom about the messaging between front-end and back-end (via ZeroMQ).

Is it possible to accept the request of shutting down from a notebook (which is received over the control socket, afaik) and then transmission the kernel into another state (e.g. bringing the remote lab back into a starting position)?

If you need any more details, please let me know!